# Phrase "raising _____" meaning to take an issue up one level to supervisors

Tags: phrase-requests

I seem to remember a phrase, perhaps starting with *raise* or *raising*, meaning to take an issue (such as one mentioned in an email message) and involve the next level of responsible parties in a hierarchy of supervisors.

(raising up the chain?)

Does anyone know of such a phrase?

Comment: ... raising the ante? stakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[raise an issue with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raise+with) the supervisors

> to bring up a matter with someone. I will raise that question with Mary when she comes in. Please raise the question with the boss. [TFD]

[escalate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/escalate) an issue to the supervisor

> To pass (a transaction or case) on to a higher level in an organizational hierarchy: escalated the customer's complaint. [TFD]

[run it up the chain of command](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/chain-of-command.html)

> You should always take things up the chain of command in the correct order and not cut anyone out of it. [Business Dictionary]

Comment: *Escalate* is the one I have both heard and used most often.

Comment: 'Raising an issue' is obviously a different usage, and your other suggestions are of different forms.